# Unable To Store Values In Excel Worksheet, Was Working Yesterday

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

The line Excel.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(wkshtName).Range("A" & n + 1) = part_name_string is not working but doesn't generate any errors, so I can't see what the issue is.

I've debugged the program several times. All values are as they should be. In the final line the workbook is open and active, wkshtName has the correct value, and part_name_string is not empty.

```
Sub WordGrab()
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim SentenceWords
    Dim arrayofWords
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim ID_array
    Dim part_name_string As String
    Dim ParagraphCount As Integer
    Dim part_name_array(6) As String

    Dim oXL As Excel.Application 'Requires loading "Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library" from Tools -> References
    Dim oWB As Excel.Workbook
    Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim oRng As Excel.Range
    Dim ExcelWasNotRunning As Boolean
    Dim WorkbookToWorkOn As String 'Path of Excel workbook
    Dim wkshtName As String 'Name of Excel worksheet
wkshtName = "My Worksheet"

WorkbookToWorkOn = "C:\ …"

On Error Resume Next
Set oXL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

If Err Then 'If Excel was not started, starts Excel
    ExcelWasNotRunning = True
    Set oXL = New Excel.Application
End If

    Set oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open(FileName:=WorkbookToWorkOn) 'Opens Excel workbook

   ''''' several lines later ''''''

ParagraphCount = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count

    For n = 1 To ParagraphCount
            SentenceWords = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(n) ' Takes all text in the n'th paragraph and stores in string / variant
            arrayofWords = Split(SentenceWords, "|") 'Cuts paragraph into different strings separated by |
            ID_array = Split(arrayofWords(0), " ") 'Stores the first string in arrayofWords in ID_array
            I = 1 ‘Initializes I at the second string in arrayofWords

            While Len(arrayofWords(I)) < 20 'Leaves off the last string separated by | since it will be long.
                part_name_array(I - 1) = arrayofWords(I) 'Puts the remaining strings into part_name_array
                I = I + 1
            Wend

        part_name_string = Join(part_name_array, " ") 'Combines part_name_array into one string
        part_name_string = Trim(part_name_string) 'Removes unnecessary spaces
        Excel.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(wkshtName).Range("A" & n + 1) = part_name_string 'Pastes part_name_array into the first column in the excel worksheet.
        Next n
```

I expect the value of part_name_string should be stored in A2 and so forth of the worksheet. But the worksheet remains empty after I run the code.

Comment: Get rid of `On Error Resume Next` and rerun. What error occurs, if any, and what is the error message? And on what line does it occur?

Comment: `Excel.Application` is not the `oXL` object, which you aren't using beyond opening the workbook to work with. Why dereferece the active workbook from an `Application` instance when you already have the `oWB` reference? `oWB.Worksheets(wkshtName).Range(...) = ...`

Comment: I suspect you may have a number of dangling EXCEL.EXE processes in task manager.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thank you for responding. That part of the code is not my own but some I found online. It did the job I needed at that point, and that's as far as I understand it. I will end all office processes in task manager and see if that helps.

Comment: @BigBen There is no error. I commented it out and my code still works (until the end). It was a miscellaneous part of someone else's code I borrowed.

EDIT: Nevermind. If Excel is not running then I get a run-time error 429. That's what that line prevents.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Your suspicions were true and my code is now running perfectly. Thank you! I will remember that as part of my de-bugging process in the future. Do you have any advice or comment to make about how that happened and how to avoid it?

Comment: When you code cross-process (e.g. against Excel but hosted in Word), you want to make sure you never implicitly create or reference an `Application` instance for which you don't have a reference to (i.e. a local variable for it) - in this case your `Application` instance is `oXL`, so everything you do with the Excel object model needs to come from *that* object - otherwise, problems happen.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thank you for the explanation. You have been very helpful today.